# Jrebel Synchronize With Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jrebel

Hi this is the Eclipse Console Log, after the JRebel setup has been successfully completed. A change is made in the Java file and Synchronize is clicked.

```
 Response headers: [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, x-rebel-response: ERR_UNKNOWN_REBEL_HASH, x-rebel-responseMessage: Remoting module '5e1de368dea571c9bc1939d90988e22a746772ce' was not found, Content-Length: 0, Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 09:56:42 GMT]
[2014-11-12 02:56:42] Cannot find such project on the remote server. Maybe it is not deployed, or project's id in rebel-remote.xml file is different.
com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.RemotingException: Cannot find such project on the remote server. Maybe it is not deployed, or project's id in rebel-remote.xml file is different.
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.net.RemotingClient.performHandshake(JRebelRemoting:124)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.net.RemotingClient.beginTransaction(JRebelRemoting:77)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.Transaction.begin(JRebelRemoting:108)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.TransactionGroup.begin(JRebelRemoting:35)
    at org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.jrebel.remoting.builder.RemotingSyncPerformer.initSynchronization(RemotingSyncPerformer.java:58)
    at org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.jrebel.remoting.builder.ManualBuilder.synchronizeProject(ManualBuilder.java:57)
    at org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.jrebel.remoting.actions.SyncNowAction$1.run(SyncNowAction.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Maybe it is not deployed, or project's id in rebel-remote.xml file is different?

Answer (score 3):

As Stefan mentioned, make sure that the deployed application also has `rebel-remote.xml` - it should be inside `WEB-INF/classes` for `.war` files or root of `.jar` files. If it does exist, make sure the id-s both in workspace and deployed application are the same. If you have multiple modules, each of them should have unique remote-id.

Another thing is to make sure you'd actually need to use remoting - if you start server from the same machine, you wont, as remoting is meant for cases where the server is on different machine or in a VM. Starting from the same machine, outside from your IDE or not, you only have to make sure that the deployed application has `rebel.xmls` containing paths to class files compiled by the IDE.

If all else fails, contact support@zeroturnaround.com

Comment: Thanks. say, i have 10 different projects(and i am accessing a VM), when i click on JRebel->Enable JRebel nature, the rebel.xml(and rebel-remote.xml, when i am enabling Remote) getting generated on the same folder as in pom.xml. It should get generated inside src/main/resources.. Any idea why, it's not getting generated inside src(i'm also tried doing a module-specific build/Full(Maven) build) .
Please help